Sort posts by numeric value of custom field, and also show any other posts without that custom field
I would like to make sorting of posts on archive pages (tag, category, author...) using pre_get_posts inside functions.php.
I have some posts with custom field "rating" and value of that field is whole number, example: 1, 5, 9... It is important to note that not all posts have that custom field.
If there is set parameter in URL sort=rating I would like to display posts that have custom field "rating" on top by value of custom field "rating", and after post(s) that HAVE that custom field I would like to show any other post(s) WITHOUT that custom field.
So, in my example it would be like this:

1st is post with custom field "rating" value of "9"
2nd is post with custom field "rating" value of "5"
3rd is post with custom field "rating" value of "1"
4th is latest published post without custom field "rating"
...

I have this function, but unfortunately it shows posts in some strange order, at first place is post without custom field "rating", also it is not pure sorting by date (it's not either the last post on first place nor the oldest post on first place).
UPDATED function
function custom_sort_posts($query) {
if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_archive()) { // If it is the main query and not in the admin area and it's archive
    if (isset($_GET['sort']) && $sort === 'rating') {
    $paged = $query->get( 'paged' ) ? $query->get( 'paged' ) : 1; // Current page

    // First query: posts with custom field
    $posts_with_rating = new WP_Query( array(
        'posts_per_page' => 30,
        'paged'          => $paged,
        'meta_key'       => 'rating',
        'fields'         => 'ids',
        'orderby'        => array(
            'meta_value_num' => 'DESC',
            'date'           => 'DESC',
            ),
        ) );

    // Second query: posts without custom field
    $posts_without_rating = new WP_Query( array(
        'posts_per_page' => 30,
        'paged'          => $paged,
        'fields'         => 'ids',
        'meta_query'     => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'rating',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
            ),
        ),
        'orderby'        => 'date',
        'order'          => 'DESC',
    ) );

    // Combine posts from two queries
    $combined_ids = array_merge( $posts_with_rating->posts, $posts_without_rating->posts );

    // Set final query
    $query->set( 'post__in', $combined_ids );
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'post__in' );

    // Total number of posts
    $query->found_posts = count( $combined_ids );

    // Pagination
    $query->max_num_pages = ceil( $query->found_posts / 30 );
    }
}

}
Function works, but in my case it returns only posts with custom field, but without any posts that do not have that custom field.
I think that function is slow, probably because of 'post__in', it took about 10s on a  tag page (that tag has about 1500 posts).
Am I missing something?

In order for sorting by a meta value to work, the meta_key parameter is required (source):

Note that a meta_key=keyname must also be present in the query.

Unfortunately this will result in only posts with the meta key set to be found by the query.
From here there are two options:

Use a query to get all the posts, and sort the posts using PHP.
Execute multiple queries and combine the results.

Each option has difficulties, but I would suggest the second, as you can execute an additional query with the post IDs, to support pagination (untested):
$posts_with_rating = new WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key'       => 'rating',
    'fields'         => 'ids',
    'orderby'        => array(
        'meta_value_num' => 'DESC',
        'date'           => 'DESC',
    ),
) );

$posts_without_rating = new WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'fields'         => 'ids',
    'orderby'        => 'date',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'rating',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ),
    ),
) );

$combined = new WP_Query( array(
    'post__in' => array_merge( $posts_with_rating->posts, $posts_without_rating->posts ),
    'orderby'  => 'post__in',
) );


I updated my question with function you provided, but I get only posts which have custom field, but without any other posts that do not have that particular custom field.

You'll probably need to analyze the whole WP_Query object, make sure it's clear of other inherited properties. Also, probably shouldn't set found_posts and max_num_pages.
